# How Discord reads memory from games?

Tags: memory, discord

For example, Discord can read what kind of lobby you are in Fortnite and what's your progress on missions called "Battlepass". Same with League of Legends and many other games I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord does not read memory of games, or at least not directly.

Rather, game developers can implement the rich presence API from Discord to provide that information.

You can look at the [official documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/rich-presence/how-to)

Comment: Thanks! I thought of this too but think myself, huge game companies like Riot Games and Epic Games wouldn't bother implementing something like this.

Comment: Actually, Riot game did implement it. A reference to this can be found on the forums at https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/skin-champion-concepts/oI0I3H20-discord-rich-presence-using-the-api. You'd be surprised what game developers would do. Being a former owner for a G15 Logitech keyboard, I was always surprised at how many of them bothered implementing support for it!